# Buttons doesnt fit to screen xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

hey i have to add +20 buttons in my app

i use this code

```
var layout = new StackLayout() {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
        };


for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var button = new Button
            {
                Text =  i.ToString(),
                HeightRequest = 45,
                WidthRequest = 45,
                Margin = 5,
                BorderRadius = 100,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,


            };
            grid.Children.Add(button);

        }
        Content = layout;



    }
```

so now buttons are going away from screen

i have to get something like that

[image]

Comment: either use a Grid or a FlexLayout

Comment: in new on xamarin can you send me a link for this please?

Comment: can you write an example code i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

use a [FlexLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout) instead of a `StackLayout`

```
    var layout = new FlexLayout();

    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var button = new Button
        {
            Text =  i.ToString(),
            HeightRequest = 45,
            WidthRequest = 45,
            Margin = 5,
            BorderRadius = 100,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        };

        layout.Children.Add(button);

    }

    Content = layout;
```